# Hiding physic body boundaries

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Can somebody help me to solve a problem of hiding visible physic body boundary? I try to create simple breakout game on cocos2d-x v3.5 and code for adding ball looks:

```
void Arkanoid::CreateBall()
{
    m_pBall = Sprite::create("ball.png");
    m_BallPosition = Vec2(m_PaddlePosition.x, m_PaddlePosition.y + m_pPaddle->getContentSize().height);
    m_pBall->setPosition(m_BallPosition);
    m_pBall->setScale(0.7);

    m_pBallBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(BALL_RADIUS, PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT);
    m_pBallBody->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    m_pBallBody->getShape(0)->setRestitution(1.0f);
    m_pBallBody->getShape(0)->setFriction(0.0f);
    m_pBallBody->getShape(0)->setDensity(1.0f);
    m_pBallBody->setDynamic(true);
    m_pBallBody->setGravityEnable(false);
    m_pBallBody->setVelocityLimit(1000.f);

    m_pBall->setTag(1);
    m_pBall->setPhysicsBody(m_pBallBody);

    this->addChild(m_pBall);
}
```

When my ball sprite adds to scene it's have circle red boundary 
around. All my other objects has it too. I know that this depends from:

```
m_pBallBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(BALL_RADIUS, PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT);
m_pBall->setPhysicsBody(m_pBallBody);
```

But I dont know how to hide them. Maybe is it possible to create physic body and sprite on different layers?

Comment: It is DebugDraw turned on. Check if you have `void draw()` method overwritten or any `setDebugDrawMask` method call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have `getDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL)` method call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's debug display. Look for:

```
->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
```

Kill or comment out this line, or change it to

```
->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_NONE);
```

I recommend commenting it out to save yourself from trouble of googling to turn the debug display back on should you need it.